# How to get multi-dimensional array's last array value in Opencart

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, opencart

I am using Opencart framework, and I customized Opencart mobile API. The thing is that I get an array like this

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 20
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 49
        [price] => 280.0000
        [value] => 1000.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    ) 
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 20
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 49
        [price] => 280.0000
        [value] => 1000.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 21
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 50
        [price] => 140.0000
        [value] => 500.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    ) 
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 20
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 49
        [price] => 280.0000
        [value] => 1000.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 21
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 50
        [price] => 140.0000
        [value] => 500.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    ) 
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 20
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 49
        [price] => 280.0000
        [value] => 1000.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 21
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 50
        [price] => 140.0000
        [value] => 500.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 232
        [product_option_value_id] => 32
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 50
        [price] => 25.0000
        [value] => 500.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
```

So that , I want to get the last or final array value,

in the given array list this is must be my final array

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 20
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 49
        [price] => 280.0000
        [value] => 1000.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 228
        [product_option_value_id] => 21
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 50
        [price] => 140.0000
        [value] => 500.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [product_option_id] => 232
        [product_option_value_id] => 32
        [option_id] => 13
        [option_value_id] => 50
        [price] => 25.0000
        [value] => 500.00000000
        [name] => please select weight
        [type] => select
        )
    )
```

Somebody help me to solve this problem.

Comment: array_pop() might be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many ways to make it, but there may be some difference.

`end($array)` or `$array[count($array) -1]` leave the original array unchanged.

`array_pop($array)` will remove the last element from the original array.